# Registration showing password does not match

Tags: django, forms, authentication

I am a beginner that start from python crash course. In the chapter 19, registration, when I tried to register user, it always have this line "Your username and password didn't match. Please try again."

Views.register

```
def register(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm()
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # account created
            new_user = form.save()
            # Check the username and password is correct
            # password is hashed, cannot retrieve normally
            authenticated_user = authenticate(username=new_user.username,
                                              password=request.POST['password1'])
            # login to the user account
            login(request,authenticated_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:index'))

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'users/register.html',context)
```

register.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}


    <!-- the action is the views url that handle the form --->
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'users:login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button name="register">
            Register
        </button>

        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

login.html

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p>
            Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.
        </p>
    {% endif %}


    <!-- the action is the views url that handle the form --->
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'users:login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <button name="login">
            Login
        </button>

        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url 'learning_logs:index' %}">
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

I tried to look out for many solutions but all that does not work. Hopefully someone here can assist me to check on my code.

Comment: I'm the author of Python Crash Course. This looks like code from the first edition of the book, which is far out of date at this point. The third edition was released early this year, and is fully up to date.